# selenium webdriver how to find stacked elements by name and xpath/tagname

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a hard time understanding the webdriver, mainly because if you find by elements you cant transverse an element that way, it always appears to go back to the driver and not the element you're on.

I'm basically trying to find a table within an `<a>` with a name

Here is the html.  There is several tables nested within a elements.  So I want to try to find the `<a>` by name and then target the table

This is what i've tried
`driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@name='description'] and //table"));` but this cannot find the element

`<a name="description">`
`<br><br><b><u>Case Description</u></b><br><br>`
`<table>
<tbody><tr valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Case ID:</b></td><td>&nbsp;CP5
 - YOMI
<i>-NON JURY TRIAL</i><br>
</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Filing Date:</b></td><td>&nbsp;Friday   , March     20th, 2009
</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Type:</b>
</td><td>&nbsp;4A - DEBT
</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Status:</b>
</td><td>&nbsp;ENT
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</a>`

Answer (score 0):

//a[@name='description']//table